# Vowel check - array out of bounds error

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm trying to write a program which accepts a word in lowercase, converts it into uppercase and changes the vowels in the word to the next alphabet. So far, I've done this:

```
import java.util.*;
class prg11
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word in lowercase.");
        String word = sc.next();
        word = word.toUpperCase();
        int length = word.length();
        char ch[] = new char[length+1];
        for (int i = 0; i<=length; i++)
        {
            ch[i] = word.charAt(i);
            if("aeiou".indexOf(ch[i]) == 0)
            {
                ch[i]+=1;
            }
        }
        String str = new String(ch);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine. But, when I run the program and enter a word, say 'hey', the word is printed in uppercase only. The vowels in it (in this case, 'e'), do not get changed to the next alphabet. 
How do I resolve this? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it, let me know if it doesn't

```
public class prg11 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word.");
    String word = sc.next();
    sc.close();
    word = word.toUpperCase();
    int length = word.length();
    char ch[] = new char[length+1];
    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
        ch[i] = word.charAt(i);
        if("AEIOU".indexOf(ch[i]) > -1) {
            ch[i]+=1;
        }
    }
    String str = new String(ch);
    System.out.println(str);
}
}
```

Let me know if it works. 
Happy coding ;) -Charlie

Answer (score 3):

Need to change three places, according to the code in the question.

```
word = word.toUpperCase();
int length = word.length();

// yours: char ch[] = new char[length + 1];
// resulting array needs to be as same length as the original word
// if not, there will be array index out of bound issues
char ch[] = new char[length];

// yours: for (int i = 0; i<=length; i++)
// need to go through valid indexes of the array - 0 to length-1
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    ch[i] = word.charAt(i);
    // yours: if ("aeiou".indexOf(ch[i]) == 0) {
    // two problems when used like that
    // 1. indexOf() methods are all case-sensitive
    //    since you've uppercased your word, need to use AEIOU
    // 2. indexOf() returns the index of the given character
    //    which would be >= 0 when that character exist inside the string
    //    or -1 if it does not exist
    //    so need to see if the returned value represents any valid index, not just 0
    if ("AEIOU".indexOf(ch[i]) >= 0) {
        ch[i] += 1;
    }
}
```

Here's a little concise version. Note the changes I've done.

```
String word = sc.next().toUpperCase();
char ch[] = word.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    if ("AEIOU".indexOf(ch[i]) >= 0) {
        ch[i] += 1;
    }
}
```

Java doc of [indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)).

```
public int indexOf(int ch)

Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character.
If a character with value ch occurs in the character sequence represented by this String object,
then the index (in Unicode code units) of the first such occurrence is returned.
For values of ch in the range from 0 to 0xFFFF (inclusive), this is the smallest value k such that:

     this.charAt(k) == ch

is true. For other values of ch, it is the smallest value k such that:

     this.codePointAt(k) == ch

is true. In either case, if no such character occurs in this string, then -1 is returned.

Parameters:
    ch - a character (Unicode code point).
Returns:
    the index of the first occurrence of the character in the character sequence represented by this object,
    or -1 if the character does not occur.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
```

instead as the last index is length-1.

Comment: Yes, I did that, and the out of bounds error is solved. But now, I'm facing another runtime error, which I've explained in my edit. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

use `for (int i = 0; i<=length-1; i++)` instead of   `for (int i = 0; i<=length; i++)` 
and `if("AEIOU".indexOf(ch[i]) != -1)` instead of `if("aeiou".indexOf(ch[i]) == 0)`

reason 
1.array index starts from 0 that's why `length-1` 
2. As you already made your string in upper case so check condition on "AEIOU" 
3. every non-vowel character will return -1 so use `if("AEIOU".indexOf(ch[i]) != -1)`

Answer (score 1):

`"aeiou".indexOf(ch[i]) == 0` will only match 'a' characters (since that is the character at index 0).  You should be looking for any index that is greater than -1.  Additionally, since you've already converted the string to uppercase, you should be checking against "AEIOU" instead of "aeiou".